# LinkedIn: "Add to profile" button not working in mobile browser, when LinkedIn App not installed on device

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to create a button to "Add to profile" on LinkedIn

In the LinkedIn documentation, there is an easy solution to "Add to profile" certificates, by using a simple URL, that should open prefilled form.
Here is example from documentation:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME&name=Test%20Certificate&organizationId=1337&issueYear=2018
&issueMonth=2&expirationYear=2020&expirationMonth=5&certUrl=
https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flearn%2Fcertifications%2Fd365-functional-consultant-sales&certId=1234"><img src="https://download.linkedin.com/desktop/add2profile/buttons/en_US.png " alt="LinkedIn Add to Profile button"></a>
```

It is working on desktop and mobile browsers, when LinkedIn App is installed.

But on mobile devices without LinkedIn application, it is not working.

Is there a solution for mobile browsers? Or option to check if LinkedIn is installed on device?

LinkedIn documentation: https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/#certs